# path file excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a file with over 50 formulas based on path file(differents).

An example of file is `c:\2017\03\report` and next month it would be `c:\2017\04\report`.

I want to change let's say in cell `A1` `sheets1` to update it on every sheets.

Aside for edit links, is there a way to do it?

Comment: Are you saying the the **sub-directory** changes every month, but the **filename** remains the same??

Comment: Yes this is it. the month and year change

Comment: @Mdh You can use INDIRECT in your formulas if all the workbooks are open.

Comment: What do you mean by indirect?

Comment: The spreadsheet can get its (own) file name and calculate the value - if this is the question.

Answer (score 0):

Given the fact that you do not want to edit links, one possible solution is to create a separate sub-directory:

```
C:\Current\
```

Each month copy the most recent file into the sub-directory.  This will insure that any time you run the spreadsheet, it will pickup the most current data with no link edit at all.

*(I had a client who used this approach because they viewed changing formulas as risky and moving a single file as easy)*

Comment: current plus the path?

Comment: @Mdh  You would always access the same file:  ***C:\Current\report***

Answer (score 0):

Does this worksheet function helps you?

```
="C:\" & YEAR(TODAY()) & "\" & REPT("0",2 - LEN(MONTH(TODAY()))) & MONTH(TODAY())
```

Good luck

Comment: I don’t think so because my formula contains a reference to another workbook

Comment: My answer is just a way to show you how you can make a string, consisting of the current year and the current month.